# HANA R Kerberos authentication

Tags: r, hana, rodbc, rjdbc

I was referring the HANA R connecting document from [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/randsaphana-dkom.pdf).

In a username password scenario it works perfect. But in the case of Kerberos what will be the Kerberos parameters for HANA Kerberos authentication?

Comment: You installed a SAP ODBC driver, right? What about reading its documentation?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter : I am going though the same. Was looking for a quick tutorial . Specific to Driver files for HANA Kerberos.